# how can i run this script in html?

Tags: html, node.js, exe, appjs

I create a b.js script file like below. when i run this using node.exe program then it correctly open "word2code.exe" file.
How can i add this script in a .html page (as link or button onclick event) in appjs for windows?

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;
var fun =function(){
   console.log("fun() start");
     exec('word2code.exe', function(err, data) {  
     console.log(err)
    console.log(data.toString());                       
  });  
}
fun();
```

Comment: Tried linking this code to the HTML document using `<script src="~/b.js" />` ?

Comment: Do you want to execute client Application?

Comment: I want to run an .exe file from a html page using node.js in appjs.
(As possible as i know it is not possible to run .exe file using simple javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run an exe directly on the client side in an HTML page -- the browser cannot understand binaries. Instead, if you basically want to fire off a process like this, you could take another approach:

- Build a website that has a button.
- This button, when clicked, should make a request to your server on some URL (like /execute).
- Write a separate web server process on your windows machine, that runs the web server.
- Write a route on your web server that handles /execute requests.
- Make this route run your exe file LOCALLY ON YOUR SERVER when the route is executed.

By doing things this way, you're essentially allowing a web user to run an exe indirectly (*your server will be the one running the binary, not the user*).

Answer (score 0):

Node.js runs on the server.  The browser is on the client side.  You cannot execute a nodejs app from the browser as the environment does not support nodejs.